# Find the first vowel in a word

Tags: matlab

Please write a Matlab function to find the first vowel in a word, and test the program using your name as the input.

The function header is `function v = findfirstvowel (word)`

My work is :

```
function v = findfirstvowel (word)
   vow = 'aeiouAEIOU';
   for i=1:size(word)
       for j=1:10
           if word(i)==vow(j)
               v=word(i);
               break;
           end
       end
    end
```

I don't know why but I didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` only breaks out of the innermost for loop.

From the documentation:

> In nested loops, break exits only from the loop in which it occurs. Control passes to the statement that follows the end of that loop.

If you want to exit the function, you'd want to use `return` instead.

```
function v = findfirstvowel (word)
   vow = 'aeiouAEIOU';
   for i=1:size(word)
       for j=1:10
           if word(i)==vow(j)
               v=word(i);
               return;
           end
       end
    end
```

Instead of the double for loop, you'd be much better off using something like [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check to find the vowels and use `find` to return the index of the first one. Also you can convert the word to lowercase and only compare to `'aeiou'`.

```
function v = findfirstvowel (word)
    isvowel = ismember(lower(word), 'aeiou');
    v = word(find(isvowel, 1, 'first'));
end
```

If you wanted the other vowels using this approach you could do the following.

```
isvowel = ismember(lower(word), 'aeiou');
vowels = word(isvowel);

first_vowel = vowels(1);
second_vowel = vowels(2);
```

Comment: the code for the second vowel is the same as first ? could you explain more how to do ?

Comment: @BBo Do you want all vowels or just the first or the second?

Comment: just the first one but I want to see that how to put the second too .

Comment: this is a function so when I run findfirstvowel (mike) it won't work because of the name is not string type. Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: @BBo What type is the name? I updated my answer to include it as a function

Comment: for example. if I want to run this function I have to type findfirstvowel(henry)  but this won't work, it only work when I change to findfirstvowel('henry'). is there any way to get rid of ' ' ?

Comment: @BBo No you need to specify it as a string like that. Otherwise you could do `name = 'henry'; findfirstvowel(name)`